# pyenv+conda doesn't install packages

Tags: python, conda, pyenv

I am trying to install packages using `conda` but nothing happens. `conda` doesn't find numpy:

```py
$ python -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

But when I try to install `numpy` using `conda` I just get:

```
$ conda install numpy
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

And there is no way to force `conda` to install it anyway:

```
$ conda install --force-reinstall numpy
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: {HOME}/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest

  added / updated specs:
    - numpy



Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Is there a solution to make `conda` really install packages? Or do I really have to uninstall everything and install everything again? Or is there even a solution to install python (using `mkl`) that is less horrible than `conda`?

---

My environment is set up (using `pyenv`), to use the `conda` installation:

```
$ which python
{HOME}/.pyenv/shims/python
```

and e.g.

```
$ python -c "import tqdm; print(tqdm.__file__)"
{HOME}/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/__init__.py
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `which $HOME/.pyenv/shims/python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

`conda install -f`, `conda install --force-reinstall` don't do anything, manually remove cache, e.g. `rm -rf {CONDA_LOCATION}/pkgs/{PACKAGE_NAME}*` followed by `conda install {PACKAGE_NAME}`.

---

I finally found a reasonable hack to force `conda` to install packages. `conda` keeps a cache which can be found using `conda info`

```
$ conda info
...
package cache : {HOME}/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/pkgs
                {HOME}/.conda/pkgs
```

Just remove everything related to the packages you want to install from the cache:

```
rm -rf {HOME}/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/pkgs/numpy*
```

(consider making backup befor performing such radical steps). Afterwards `conda` can install the packages normally:

```
$ conda install numpy
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: {HOME}.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest

  added / updated specs:
    - numpy


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    numpy-base-1.15.4          |           py36_2         6.1 MB  intel
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         6.1 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  numpy-base         intel/linux-64::numpy-base-1.15.4-py36_2


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
numpy-base-1.15.4    | 6.1 MB    | ################################################################################################################################################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Answer (score 2):

### Updated answer:

Second attempt to answer your question (I am new to using pyenv but hope this helps):

When using pyenv and miniconda I would activate your environment (miniconda3-latest from your post), then the right conda should be used to install your packages:

```sh
# Activate your environment
pyenv activate miniconda3-latest

# Install numpy, etc.
conda install numpy

# This then works without errors for me:
python -c "import numpy"

# Deactivate your environment when finish if you want
pyenv deactivate
```

As a general observation, it seems that pyenv and conda are doing similar things (see https://bastibe.de/2017-11-20-pyenv.html). I haven't explored much of pyenv yet, but if I were using it, I might consider not pairing it with conda, and just relying on native python (venv, pip) to install packages, and let pyenv do all the environment managing (instead of adding conda on top of it).

### Original answer:

I don't think there is anything nothing wrong with conda, but rather the command you have typed in is probably calling the native python on your system rather than the conda one.

These commands will let you see what path you are calling:

```sh
# for linux/mac
which python

# for windows
where python
```

If what it shows is something like `/usr/bin/python` (for linux/mac) then that's not the conda instance of python that you are calling.

If you want to call for the actual conda instance that you've installed your packages, you should find where your conda is installed to and call for it using the full path:

```sh
# taking your example it looks like your python is in
# {HOME}/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest
{HOME}/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-latest/bin/python -c "import numpy"

# or on my computer it is (~ means home):
~/anaconda3/bin/python -c "import numpy"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, but that is not the cause of the problem. I clarified my question (and removed the alias from it). Python indeed refers to the anaconda versions, `pyenv` manages my versions.

Comment: pyenv seems like a nice package! Answer modified hopefully that helps address your problem @DerWeh

Comment: thanks for the help, but sadly this doesn't solve my problem. `pyenv` is set up correctly, that's how `python` defaults to the `conda` installation. The real problem is, that `conda instal XXX` doesn't do anything. After confirming to proceed, it **does not install** `numpy`. It neither downloads nor install `numpy`. If possible I would keep my hands off `conda`, but currently this is the only reasonable way to install Intel backed python (mkl!).